# Upload PDF from File Chooser in android Q

Tags: android, file, retrofit, android-10.0

What is the best/recommended method to upload PDF (or other "doc" files) from File Chooser? Since there's many deprecated method in Android such as `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA` etc. It makes us harder to get the `File` reference to it.

What i do now is get uri from onActivityResult, copy the content to private folder, and use the private-copied `File` to upload to server. But i think that's too expensive

Is there any better-recommended-bugfree method to do?

Comment: no need to add the android-studio tag, considering that you're not asking about the IDE itself

Comment: Use one of the `InputStreamRequestBody` implementations floating around, such as [this one](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html), [this one](https://cketti.de/2020/05/23/content-uris-and-okhttp/), or [this one](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3585#issuecomment-327319196).